# Метод scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: не всегда докручивает таблицу до конца

Tags: tableview, scrollview

Метод `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` не всегда вызывает метод `tableView:didEndDisplayingHeaderView:forSection:` у предыдущей секции.

Я пытаюсь сделать коллекцию и таблицу в одном контроллере. Таблица отображает данные, делится на несколько секций, у которых есть `HeaderView`. Коллекция горизонтальная и имитирует кнопки, по нажатию на которые таблица прокручивает к нужной секции, после прокрутки таблицы я бы хотел, чтобы выбранная секция в коллекции меняла цвет, но проблема в том, что если я вручную прокручиваю таблицу, цвет должен меняться соответственно текущей секции. У меня почти получилось это реализовать, но по какой-то причине таблица иногда не докручивает один пиксель, чтобы предыдущая ячейка и `HeaderView` вызвала метод `didEndDisplaying`.

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSIndexPath *tableViewIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.row];

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:tableViewIndexPathatScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSInteger topSection = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows.firstObject.section;

if (topSection > section) {
    NSIndexPath *newTopSectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:topSection inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:newTopSectionIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
    CalendarDayCollectionViewCell *oldTopCell = (CalendarDayCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:newTopSectionIndexPath];
    [oldTopCell updateLabelColor];

    NSIndexPath *oldTopSectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:section inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:oldTopSectionIndexPath animated:YES];
    CalendarDayCollectionViewCell *newTopCell = (CalendarDayCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:oldTopSectionIndexPath];
    [newTopCell updateLabelColor];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Временно решил проблему методом

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y + 1)
}
```

Но хотелось бы обойтись без костылей.